# number of solutions to $(x+t)^a=x^a$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=p^m$ ($p$ is prime) denote a finite field. For any $t\in\mathbb{F}_q^*$ and a ratioanl number $a$, consider the equation
$$
(x+t)^a=x^a
$$

Let $A(t,a)$ denote the number of solutions to the above equation in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then can we bound $A(t,a)$ by a constant depending only on $a$ (i.e. independent of $q$ and $t$)? Will the answer be different if we only consider the special case $m=1$ (i.e. $q=p$)?

Comment: I'm confused about what happens when $a$ is not an integer. How do you handle root extraction when $a$ is not an integer (say, $\frac{1}{n}$)? Do you just raise both sides to the $n^{th}$ power? It seems to me like $a$ ought to be an integer, but perhaps this is a statement made out of ignorance.

Comment: @KReiser If we allow $x$ to be in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$, then I think it is OK to talk about fractional power. But I notice the uniqueness issue: there may be so many candidates when we write $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Like KReiser I am worried about the meaning of $x^a$ for non-integer exponent $a$ in a finite field. On the other hand, if $a=r/s$ with integers $r,s$ then we **can** define $x^{r/s}$ as the unique solution $z\in\Bbb{F}_q$ of the equation
$$
x^r=z^s\qquad(*)
$$
**when and only when $\gcd(s,q-1)=1$.** Without the gcd-condition the equation $(*)$ may have no solutions at all, or it will have $\gcd(s,q-1)$ distinct solutions. This follows from cyclicity of the group $\Bbb{F}_q^*$.

So we need to assume that either $a$ is an integer or $a=r/s$ with $\gcd(s,q-1)=1$. We can make the following observations:

- When $\gcd(s,q-1)=1$ we have $(x+t)^{r/s}=x^{r/s}$ if and only if $(x+t)^r=x^r$, so we can ignore the denominator and $A(t,r/s)=A(t,r)$.
- For the same reason we have $A(t,ks)=A(t,k)$ for all integers $k$ and all integers $s$ such that $\gcd(s,q-1)=1$.
- As a corollary of the previous observation we have $A(t,a)=A(t,\gcd(a,q-1))$ whenever $a$ is an integer. In other words, without loss of generality we can assume that $a\mid q-1$
- The equation $(x+t)^r=x^r$ can be viewed as a polynomial equation of degree $r-1$, so we have the trivial upper bound $A(t,r)\le r-1$.
- The substitution $x=ty$ (recall that $t\neq0$) transforms $(x+t)^a=x^a$ to $t^a(y+1)^a=t^ay^a$ which is obviously equivalent to $(y+1)^a=y^a$. Consequently $$A(t,a)=A(1,a)$$ for all exponents $a$ and all $t\neq0$.

Edit: I misremembered, and thought that the equation occurs in the study of so called almost perfect non-linear mappings. But, there the equation of interest is $(x+t)^a=x^a+b$. Instead, we can  proceed from this point as pointed out by Jake Levinson (see comments below).

Comment: Am I missing something? From your reduction to $(y+1)^a = y^a$, we clearly see $y \ne 0$, so we reduce to $(1 + 1/y)^a = 1$, and so $1 + 1/y$ is a root of unity.

Comment: By God, @JakeLevinson! You're right. Something doesn't add up now...

Comment: Yup. Figured out the mistake. I was dead set on referring people to APN functions, but that is something slightly different. @JakeLevinson Do you want to type that as an answer?

Comment: That's alright - just a final little detail, might as well just be part of your answer.